# How to find number of occurrences of specified string within a long hashset?

Tags: c#

I have a text file with most words in the English dictionary. I've created a hashset that contains each word so that I can compare a word to it and see if it is a real word. I now need to determine the number of times a certain string occurs in it.

For example, let's say a hashset contains the words: {"hello", "hi", "houses", "holder"}. If I want to check the number of occurrences of the string "ho", it should return the integer 2. Also, I want to do this instantly (in O(1) time).

I've tried making the hashset a string and checking that way with regex.matches, but it's simply way too long.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see how this can be faster than O(n), if you're looking for an arbitrary string within every word.

Comment: O(1) is for lookup of the hashed objects. Searching for partial strings doesn't qualify, so it can't be O(1). `foreach (string item in hashSet) if (item.Contains("ho")) counter++;` is probably as fast as you could get.

Comment: You need something like string Trie (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) but it would be O(n) I believe

Comment: What ever method you use, it has to check each and every word to see if it contains your search word.

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux: A trie would solve the problem of "strings that begin with a substring" but not the problem of substrings within a string. It's not clear from the question whether "choke" would be matched. If not, a trie is ideal. If yes, here are other options https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String-searching_algorithm

Comment: Without preparing the data, I wouldn't know a way: https://dotnetfiddle.net/cLeMT4

Comment: @EricJ. Yes, I stand corrected. But hashes definitely won't work

Comment: @EricJ. I think trie is fine - you just push all the suffixes of the word rather than just word itself. Still can't really get O(1) but O(len(string-to-find)) which you get with trie lookup (need to use dictionary in each node rather than some more compact structures like linked list) , sounds pretty reasonable.

Comment: I'm afraid you would need to know all possible queries to make it O(1). The best-suited algorithm for that kind of problem should be Burrows-Wheeler Transform. Its O(log(n)) for querying the occurrences of a particular string but its O(n^2log(n)) for creating the data structure. Changing the dataset will require recomputing the data structure

Answer (score 0):

As you only mentioned the query time to be O(1) and not the creation of data structure we can do some bad things to achieve that.

1. We create a `Dictionary<string>` for a string and the number of occurrences of that string
2. We iterate through every string in `HashSet` we add every possible substring to `Dictionary<string, int>`. If substring does not exist we do `.Add(s, 1)` else we increment the string occurrances.

After that, you should be able to search in the `Dictionary<string, int>` in O(1).

Something like this:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
var hash = new HashSet<string> { "hello", "hi", "houses", "holder" };

foreach(var item in hash) 
{
    for(int i = 0; i < item.Length - 1; i++)
    for(int j = i + 1; j < item.Length; j++) 
    {
        var s = item.Substring(i, j - i);
        if(!dict.ContainsKey(s)) 
        {
            dict.Add(s, 0);
        }
        dict[s]++;
    }

}
```

And you got `O(m*n^2)` for data structure but querying is O(1).
If you do data structure calculation once in a lifetime this should do a good job. Creation of data structure will take time but it should be expected in some scenarios and you need some memory to store those `string`s.

To query for `ho` you use:

```
public int Query(string x) => dict.ContainsKey(x) ? dict[x] : 0;
```